# Remove array elements at different indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have an array given below:

`var box=[1,2,3,4,5]
 var sum=6;`

In my if condition I check if there is a combination available for sum variable, remove the element(s) from array. For example in case above it will remove `6` from array if available else it will look for combination i.e `(2,4)` and remove these from array. Using `box.splice` method I am able to delete only one index in one step. Is there any other way where if the combination is found it shall delete both elements i.e `(2,4)`  from array in one step considering the fact that these are elements at two different indexes which are nonadjacent.

Comment: No. You could do a `filter`, but really `splice` is the only in-place remove method. There's nothing wrong with using multiple steps, but make sure to begin at the end so that indices don't change by removing something in front.

Comment: thank you it worked by beginning at the end index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to achieve this.

For example if you know the indexes of the values you could do something like this:

```
box = box.filter((num, index) => index !== index1 && index !== index2);
```

Or for a more robust solution:

```
const combination = [2, 4];

box = box.filter(num => {
    if (combination.includes(num)) {
        // remove first occurence of num from combination
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```